# Dart code in Android Studio Electric Eel doesn't look good after formatting

Tags: flutter, dart, android-studio

After formatting code in Android Studio, it doesn't look good! Are there any additional settings?

[image]

Answer (score -2):

This formatting works w.r.t the hard wrap line at right.

You can change it in settings. **settings > Editor > Code style > hard wrap**

There are also options for specific language.[image]